# Google calendar API not showing the response from the app in web google calendar after replying to an event's invitation

Tags: php, ios, google-calendar-api

We are building a iOS calendar app which integrates with google calendar. We have synced google calendar in the backend and everything works fine so far but we have a small issue. When the user responds to an event invitation's "yes", "no", "maybe" in the iOS app, The user's response could not be seen on the google calendar web page and the invitee is not receiving any response. We are not getting any errors.

### The programming language is php. Below is the code.

```
    require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php';
    require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Service.php';

    /* setup google client object */
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId('303546570344-ttv0ingquts4thesu9ub93l2473f6ras.apps.googleusercontent.com');

    /* refresh access token */
    $google_refresh_token = 'ya29.Ci92A7X95zK0U0CQptu3HU5x0P0jJptcTLZYtG5U2xU2EO3lgOJvdFa9oHYYT6pfDA';

    $client->refreshToken($google_refresh_token);
    $newToken = $client->getAccessToken();
    $newToken = 'ya29.Ci92A7X95zK0U0CQptu3HU5x0P0jJptcTLZYtG5U2xU2EO3lgOJvdFa9oHYYT6pfDA';
    $client->setAccessToken($newToken);

    $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
    $event = $service->events->get('primary', 'm2k54p8hcas6iup1ken7o5g5ac');
    $attendee1 = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventAttendee();
    $attendee1->setEmail('admin@frejun.com');
    $attendee1->setResponseStatus('accepted');
    $attedess = $event->getAttendees();
    $attedess[0] = $attendee1;
    $event->setAttendees($attedess);
    $updatedEvent = $service->events->update('primary', $event->getId(), $event);
    echo $updatedEvent->getUpdated();
```

---

Any help would be very much appreciated and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your created event may have a property `sendNotifications` set to false (by default) that is why you are not receiving any response by the user.

You might want to check how the event behave in [update](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) and [insert](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) documentations.

> **sendNotifications**
>
> - Whether to send notifications about the event update (e.g. attendee's responses, title changes, etc.). Optional. The default is `False`.

Also base on this - [Reminders and Notifications](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts/reminders)

> To send email notifications to attendees for events that were inserted or updated via the API, set the **`sendNotifications`** parameter in the insert/update request to true.

[image]

Following the said implementation may help you be notified if any updates happens (e.g. attendee's responses, title changes, etc.) related to the event.

Hope this helps.